# Maintaining correct spacing around operators

Tags: notebooks, formatting, style

How can I create mathematical expressions (just for the looks) which have correct spacing around the operator?  I want to use display these in arbitrary places, such as labels in a GUI, tick labels or within `Text`/`Inset` in `Graphics`, etc.

---

Here's an example of entering $a\times b$ in an input cell as `a \[Times] b`.  The spacing is perfect, and automatically determined.

If I enter the same in a string or create it with `Row`, then the spacing is too small.

[image]

How can I assemble this expression given an arbitrary `a` and `b` (say, $a = 5$ and $b = 10^{6}$), and maintain correct spacing around the operator?  In some cases `HoldForm` helps, but multiplication isn't always formatted with `\[Times]` so I cannot use it in this case.

I can adjust the spacing in `Row` manually in several ways, but I don't want to do this.  I want to let Mathematica determine the spacing automatically, and have it consistent with expressions I type into an input cell.

---

When I type $a\times b$ into an input cell, the underlying representation is just `RowBox[{"a", "\[Times]", "b"}]`.  There is something about the `"Input"` cell style that causes the front end to interpret `\[Times]` as an operator and create the correct spacing.  What is it?  It doesn't happen for all cells style (e.g. not for `"Code"`).

Comment: It seems the key is `AutoSpacing`. Now I have to figure out how to use this to create a display that can be inserted anywhere in the notebook, including graphics.

Comment: In my system (I haven't messed with autospacing) `Row[...]` and `a \[Times] b` have the same spacing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQiSR.png

Comment: @gpap What version of M do you have?  Let me try that again.

Comment: @gpap I see your screenshot, but I can't get any M between 9 and 11 to behave that way.  I'm on OS X.

Comment: osx 10.10.5 and MMA 10.3.0.0 - I got distracted by an email and forgot to write that :D

Comment: @gpap Tried on OS X 10.12.0, M10.3.1, still no luck.  Do you have any special stylesheets or cutomizations?

Comment: I can't think of anything I am doing out of the ordinary my init.m only confines the history length

Comment: @gpap Could you please do a `FullForm` on that `Row` expression and see what it is?  Here's mine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I0ab0.png  If it's the same as mine, could you see the cell expression of the output (like in my screenshot)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46631/discussion-between-gpap-and-szabolcs).

Comment: wouldn't it be great if the f/e used TeX for its output? Perfect typesetting, perfect traditional form, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure, if I correctly understuud your ultimate aim. I take it that you will only use the expressions for demonstration in a notebook or as a part of an image (say, graphics). If this is true, may be using `Spacer` may help. Let us take your example with and without the spacer:

```
    Row[{"a", "\[Times]", "b"}]
    Row[{"a", Spacer[2.5], "\[Times]", Spacer[2], "b"}]
```

it yields

[image]

the second example has somewhat larger spaces between the symbols. One can do the same also by using the BoxLanguage:

```
  StyleBox[RowBox[{"a", Spacer[2.5], "\[Times]", Spacer[1], "b"}], 
  SpanMaxSize -> Infinity] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

I hope it helps. Have fun!

---

You can also use the option you mentioned, [`AutoSpacing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoSpacing.html).  This is an option for `Cell`, so we must use `DisplayForm` to show the result in the notebook:

```
DisplayForm[
 Cell[BoxData@RowBox[{4, "\[Times]", SuperscriptBox[10, 5]}], AutoSpacing -> True]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I explicitly asked not to put in the space manually.  I need the spacing to be as determined by the front end.  So `Spacer` is not an acceptable solution.  But `DisplayForm` (which I wasn't aware of) combined with `AutoSpacing` does solve the problem!  Thank you.  `DisplayForm[
 Cell[BoxData@RowBox[{4, "\[Times]", SuperscriptBox[10, 5]}], 
  AutoSpacing -> True]]`.

Comment: I went ahead and edited this into your answer so I can feel content accepting it :-) I hope you don't mind about the edit.  It can always be undone.

Comment: @Szabolcs I do not mind, by I do not deserve it: I did not know about such an option. Even more, when I tried to evaluate ` Options[DisplayForm]` Mma returnd an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The cell created when you enter `a \[Times] b` can be examined by using `Cell | Show Expression` on the input cell:

> Cell[BoxData[
>    RowBox[{"a", "\[Times]", "b"}]], "Input",
>    CellChangeTimes->{{3.764961916060225*^9, 3.764961918981412*^9}}]

Alternatively, consider the boxes generated for typical binary operations:

```
a.b //ToBoxes
```

> RowBox[{"a", ".", "b"}]

```
a+b //ToBoxes
```

> RowBox[{"a", "+", "b"}]

So, to get the nice front end spacing you observe, you need to construct a similar structure. One way to do this is to use Row with a second argument of None:

```
Row[{a, "\[Times]", b}, None]
```

> [image]

Let's see what the underlying box structure is for the above:

```
ToBoxes @ Row[{a, "\[Times]", b}]
```

> TemplateBox[{"a", "\"\[Times]\"", "b"}, "RowDefault"]

Oops, we get a TemplateBox. Let's use an internal function to convert this to ordinary boxes:

```
BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes @ ToBoxes@Row[{a, "\[Times]", b},None]
```

> RowBox[{"a", "\"\[Times]\"", "b"}]

To be even more similar to how things like `a + b` are converted to boxes, you can use [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes). Basically, `ToBoxes @ RawBoxes[boxes]` returns `boxes`. So:

```
BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes@ ToBoxes@Row[{a, RawBoxes@"\[Times]", b},None]
```

> RowBox[{"a", "\[Times]", "b"}]

An alternative to using [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) is to actually create a format:

```
MakeBoxes[times[a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= RowBox @ {
    MakeBoxes[a, StandardForm], "\[Times]", MakeBoxes[b, StandardForm]
}
```

Then:

```
times[a, b]
ToBoxes @ %
```

> [image]
>
> RowBox[{"a", "\[Times]", "b"}]